# Strip Tags thats are NOT in [code] [/code] segment

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to strip tags from a user-inputted string except from tags that are wrapped in the [code] [/code] BB style tag.

For example, a user may enter this:

```
<script>alert("hacked");</script>
[code]<script>alert("hello");</script>[/code]
```

What I would like is the "hacked" alert to be removed, but not the "Hello" alert.

I would like to remove ALL tags (php, html, css, js) outside of the [code] but allow anything within them.

So far, I've got the following code to do the reverse of what I would like:

```
preg_replace('/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/ise','strip_tags(\'$1\')',$code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best algorithm, but here's an idea.

1. Remove all the `[code]` blocks into an array
2. Strip tags from the remaining string
3. Re-insert the previously removed `[code]` blocks.
4. Voila!

Here's a stab at that algo

```
<?php

header( 'Content-Type: text/plain' );

$input = <<<BB
[code]<script>alert("hello");</script>[/code]
some text <script>alert("hacked");</script> some other text
[code]<script>alert("hello");</script>[/code]
some text <script>alert("hacked");</script> some other text
[code]<script>alert("hello");</script>[/code]
BB;

echo strip_custom( $input );

function strip_custom( $content )
{
  $pattern = "#\\[code].*?\\[/code]#i";

  if ( preg_match_all( $pattern, $content, $codeBlocks ) )
  {
    return array_join( $codeBlocks[0], array_map( 'strip_tags', preg_split( $pattern, $content ) ) );
  }
  return strip_tags( $content );
}

function array_join( array $glue, array $pieces )
{
  $glue       = array_values( $glue );
  $pieces     = array_values( $pieces );
  $piecesSize = count( $pieces );

  if ( count( $glue ) + 1 != $piecesSize )
  {
    return false;
  }

  $joined = array();
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $piecesSize; $i++ )
  {
    $joined[] = $pieces[$i];
    if ( isset( $glue[$i] ) )
    {
      $joined[] = $glue[$i];
    }
  }
  return implode( '', $joined );
}
```

Comment: in the strip_custom() function, I've changed "return $content" to return strip_tags($content); as this will return the stripped out text when [code] is not present.

Thanks again

Comment: Good catch!  Added to my answer for future-proofing =)

Answer (score 1):

This is where regular expressions are not ideal. Regular expressions are superb when you know "what you *want*" but not "what you *don't* want". My suggestion is that you try to find an alternative way of doing the same thing, but without regular expressions.

Comment: can you think of any ways of achieving this without using regular expressions?

Comment: Using regular expressions to pull values from HTML is always a mistake. HTML syntax is a lot more complex that it may first appear and it's very easy for a page to catch out even a very complex regular expression.  This question does come up a lot on Stack Overflow and I think it's because Regular Expressions seems perfect for this job, but they aren't.  Use an HTML Parser instead.

Comment: @Jamie: I haven't ever done this and I don't know for sure, but my initial attempt would be to see if there are any occurrences of `"[code]"` in the text and if so, find out its position. Then I would try to find `"[/code]"` and the position of that and then work from there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an HTML Parser for this job.

I don't know PHP but Google found this [HTML Parser for PHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple parser like this:

```
stack-pointer = 0
while not finished:
    stack-pointer-n = code-start-matched or endl
    tag-free-str = regex-magic-to-strip-tags(extract-str(stack-pointer, stack-pointer-n))
    preserve-str = extract-str(stack-pointer-n, code-endl-matched or endl)
    stack-pointer = code-endl-matched + 1
    push(tag-free-str)
    push(preserve-str)
```